# Movie with ocean and dolphins inside spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a (possibly animated) Science Fiction movie in which aliens, I think, installed a device that would cool down the Earth's core. To save their planet, *one billion* humans got on a gigantic spaceship and travelled to the planet of the aliens to get something to turn that device off. The spaceship was so big it had an ocean with dolphins inside. The people on it lived in "cities" labelled 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc. and were somehow ordered alphabetically by last name.

That's about all my ten year old son can remember. He says there was also a book series with about four volumes that tells the same story.

The movie was at least one or two years old, possibly more, and dubbed in German. It may have been rated (in Germany) for 12 year olds (despite my son's age at that time).

Comment: Is your son sure this was a film? It sounds like the plot for the video game Ecco the Dolphin. More info in this wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecco_the_Dolphin

Comment: @dominicfonde Thank you, that sounds pretty close, but it cannot have been that game, because we don't own and never have owned any of the platforms necessary to play that game. That said, of course my son could misremember (or invent) parts of that storyline. You know how the memory works, especially in kids.